# Multiple entries urls performance

Tags: navigation, performance, queries

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way, performance side, to call multiple urls for a navigation element in case of a multi language site (so static links are not an option).

```
<div>
  <span><a href="{{ craft.entries.section("page1").one().url }}">Page 1</a></span>
  <span><a href="{{ craft.entries.section("page2").one().url }}">Page 2</a></span>
  <span><a href="{{ craft.entries.section("page3").one().url }}">Page 3</a></span>
</div>
```

The code above is generating alone 7 new queries, why 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using one separate query for each page, use just one query to get all pages and then iterate through them:

```twig
{% set pages = craft.entries()
    .section(['page1', 'page2', 'page3'])
    .all();
%}

<ol>
    {% for page in pages %}
        <li><a href="{{ page.getUrl() }}">{{ page.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

(Sidenote: You'll want to use `ul` or `ol` for lists so your HTML has a better semantic structure).

You can control the order of the query with the [`orderBy` parameter](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries.html#orderby).

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I was looking for.